# How do you get the output of a HLSL computation?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, xna, hlsl

I would basically like to screen capture a GPU result into a bitmap file using .NET. I would probably use XNA and my workflow would be something like:

1. Call an effect with custom input data
2. Have the effect run a per-pixel process
3. **Get the result from the effect (???)**
4. Save result as bitmap

Thanks...

---

### Edit

**Summary from Liortal's answer**:

> To use a render target, create a
>   RenderTarget2D object with the width,
>   height, and other options you prefer.
>   Then call
>   GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget to make
>   your render target the current render
>   target. From this point on, any Draw
>   calls you make will draw into your
>   render target. When you are finished
>   with the render target, call
>   GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget to a
>   new render target (or null for the
>   back buffer). Then at any time you can
>   call RenderTarget2D.GetTexture to get
>   the contents of the render target for
>   further processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read more about Render Targets and how to use them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976073.aspx

Note that the link refers up to XNA 3.1, here's a post by the awesome Shawn Hargreaves about changes made in this area in XNA 4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: Good stuff, exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`RenderTarget`'s are what you are after here.  Set the `RenderTarget` (`graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(myRenderTarget);`), draw your scene and then use either `SaveAsJpeg` or `SaveAsPng` methods to save the output.

Here is the XNA 4 version of the [RenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d_methods.aspx) documentation.

However, people have mentioned about memory leaks, so I would use this alternative:

[BmpWriter](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65527/400891.aspx)

This link has the source code that you require (as I mentioned above).